# How to create property table in an entitiy with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

I have an user Entitiy. I want to create properties for this user entitiy without another entity class.
My user entitiy is;

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class User {
          ****
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_properties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "key")
@Column(name = "value")
private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

public String setProperty(String key,String value) {
    return properties.put(key,value);
}

public String getProperty(String key) {
    return properties.get(key);
}
}
```

This codes cannot create user_properties table and I got error;

```
Table 'test.user_properties' doesn't exist
```

How can I create properties table without new entitiy for properties?

Comment: You have to create the tabel with SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support column names as 'key' and 'value'. I changed column names and It worked for me.